# Meteor not returning document field using "return" but does using console.log();

Tags: meteor, minimongo

I have a basic query to get the email list of the people in my database. When I console.log() it through console, it works great, but within the app it just doesn't.

```
// this works in console.log() but not in the app
return memberProfile.findOne({memberId: Meteor.user()._id}).email

// this is how its meant to be, where we insert each appropriate user id
return memberProfile.findOne({memberId: this._id}).email
```

I'm still getting the hang of Meteor, would much appreciate your help with learning it.

Comment: My guess is: first time when data is not available yet, your findOne will not find anything and will return undefined? try `var doc = memberProfile.findOne({memberId: this._id}); return doc ? doc.email : "placeholder@mail.com"`

Comment: I suspect Slava is correct. Reading [this post](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards) may be beneficial.

Comment: Another great article David.